# Microsoft Azure Authentication Api for user login

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Azure authentication for user Login ,

After login of user  there is change password section in my application where user provide his current password and new password so my query is

Is there is any Api(Graph) to GET Current Password for that user OR  Any API(Graph) through which we authenticate current Password which provided by user

Is there any other scenario which help me to authenticate current password which was given by user while changing password

Or any other way to get current password for that user

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the current password for users.
It would be a massive security vulnerability and imply they store them insecurely.

There is a way to authenticate a user like that, but it won't work if the user has e.g. MFA.

I would suggest a different approach. 
Check how old the authentication is (id token has the time it was issued).
If it is older than, say, 15 minutes, require the user to authenticate with AAD (prompt=login).
You can also require MFA for the login if you know all your users use it. 
Then they should be able to give a new password, which you can then set with Graph API.

So instead of making a call to check the current password, require a fresh ID token and rely on AAD to check the user credentials.

Also, the users should be able to change it themselves already as written in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/active-directory-passwords-update-your-own-password

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In our site,

There is a change password accordion in "manage account" page. There are 3 fields i.e, "current password","new password" & "Confirm new password". Entered value in current password does not validate the user's current password. 

Could you please suggest how can we validate the current password in our "manage account" page?

Please refer the url below to- https://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/account-management